# displaying list of "list views" in an org and find for whom those list views are assigned?

Tags: list-view

I need to display all the list views present in an org and i too need for whom those list views are assigned?

I have gone through workbench and got all the list views of an org , but I cant get for whom those list views are assigned.

Comment: To better answer the question, can you explain what the purpose is that you need this for?

Comment: I JUST WANT TO KNOW HOW MANY LIST VIEWS ARE THERE IN MY ORG AND FOR WHOM THOSE LISTVIEWS ARE ASSIGNED. IT IS A REQUIREMENT .I MA NOT SURE ABOUT PURPOSE.

Comment: why don't you go in and count them then?

Comment: how many can we count like that , If there are many objects and having many listviews how can we count like that. I request for a procedure to get to whom the lsit views are assigned.

Comment: the assignment does not happen on a per-user basis but for each list view it is specified which user or group of users can use the list view. Only at the time of rendering the page, the system determines the list views it will show to the user. There is no per-user report available of that. However, if this is for auditing purposes or something alike, note that the list views will always represent the security settings of the user. So they will never see records or fields they are not authorized to see.